# How do I use Firebase Authentication with a Java App Engine (standard) application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a relatively simple tutorial and/or sample app that shows all the steps necessary to do Firebase Authentication with a Java App Engine (standard) application?  I feel like I've done most of what's required but I am seeing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
```

when I run:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

My goal is then be able to do:

```
 FirebaseToken decodedToken = firebaseAuth.verifyIdTokenAsync(idTokenString).get();
 String userId = decodedToken.getUid();
 UserRecord userRecord = firebaseAuth.getUserAsync(userId).get();
```

Note that Firebase Auth is the only Firebase API or service that I'll be accessing in this application, so I'm thinking that I don't need to create a Firebase service account and setup Application Default Credentials.  Is that the case?

Experimentation suggests that I **do** need to create a Firebase service account and use the service account json credentials file.  If there is some way to avoid having to do that, I'd love to see it.

Thanks in advance.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar scenario.  After a few hours of struggle and a few reads through the docs I found this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

It is referenced by these docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

In the end ( like you eluded to ) I needed to create a Firebase Service Account.  That allowed me to follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and initialize my Firebase application in my Java Application and I no longer get the error 'FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.'.  I am now able to verify a ID token and get the uid from Firebase via 'verifyIdTokenAsync'.

As for your final question about not requiring a service account I believe you do NOT need a service account if you are running on google's java app engine.

Below is a snippet of code from that same setup page that implies what you are asking can indeed be accomplished.  I am not running on google's java app engine so I cannot confirm.  I hope this helps.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault())
.setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
.build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having an issue in which somehow it was not able to get the credentials json file in classpath. So I used the Levi's solutions more details are as:

create class:

```
public class FirebaseCredentialsHelper {

      public String type= "";
      public String project_id= "";
      public String private_key_id= "";
      public String private_key= "";
      public String client_email= "";
      public String client_id= "";
      public String auth_uri= "";
      public String token_uri= "";
      public String auth_provider_x509_cert_url= "";
      public String client_x509_cert_url= "";

}
```

Use dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is how you do the handshake.

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(gson.toJson(new FirebaseCredentialsHelper()).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(credentials).build();
```